# How to include Resource files in dotnet build with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm building a WPF application with dotnet core in the visual studio code editor. The problem I'm having is that the Resources folder isn't included with builds, or so it seems. I can't find an example of how to to do that outside of Visual Studio and any image I try to use doesn't work. Any tips or examples would be appreciated!

**Folder structure**

```
|- Root Folder
   |- bin
      |- Debug
         |- netcoreapp3.1
            |- [this has dlls and exe, but no Resources]
   |- obj
   |- Data
   |- Pages
   |- Resources
      |- images
```

**Commands to run app:**

```bsh
dotnet clean
dotnet build
dotnet run
```

It's all standard stuff so please point out any missing commands, misplaced files, etc. I'm new to WPF and trying to build windows app in VS Code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add your resource file manually to .csproj file if you want to use it as embedded resource:

```xml
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\images\icon.ico" />
```

or if you want to copy files to your build folder

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="Resources\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Hi
The "<EmbeddedRessource..." needs to be in a <ItemGroup>..</ItemGroup>, or am I wrong with that.

Answer (score 2):

*In your .csproj add*

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="Resources\Images\New Bitmap Image.bmp">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Directory structure post build:**

```
\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Resources\Images
```