# Is there a way to use relative path for reading data files for tests in Nunit 3?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, github-actions

I'm new to Nunit3 and am currently using it to run some tests and want to read test data from a file rather than hardcoding it. The test data is used as the "expected" value and I want to read from a file because it is very large. Currently, reading from an absolute path works (ex: `@"C:\path\to\TestData\testdata.txt"`). However, this is hardcoded into the `MyTest.cs` test and I want it to be relative for testing on github actions or when testing on a different system.  Is this possible?

I've tried to use things like `"TestData\testdata.txt"` but the testing context is different than the context in the source directory I believe and I get `file does not exist` errors. I have also tried to use `Path.Combine()` with `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` and `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` but the directory is not there because it doesn't get copied during the test build so the final path is incorrect.

Thanks!

```
TestAPI
|
-- src
-- API.Tests (this is a folder)
  |
  -- MyTest.cs
  -- TestData
     |
     -- testdata.txt
```

Comment: Are you able to copy the text file to the output directory when the test project is compiled?

Comment: You'd better not, as your test assemblies can be copied to a shadow folder without those files in certain cases. Try to embed those data files as resources so that your code can read from resources instead.

Comment: @LexLi How would I embed those data files as resources? Apologies for the dumb question.

Comment: You might get started from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files and Visual Studio actually makes it much easier to manage.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that a way to do this is to embed files directly into the `*.csproj`.

To do that, assuming your `TestData` is in the same directory as the `*.csproj` file, add the following to the `*.csproj` file between the `<Project></Project>` tags. This will copy all the files in the TestData directory into the build context.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="TestData\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

In your test code, you can access a file via the following, replace `testdata.txt` with your file name.

`string path = Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory, @"TestData\testdata.txt");`

Now you should be able to read data from that path now.

If there is a better way, please let me know. Thanks!

References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6080607/19831782
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29057351/19831782
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118549/19831782

Thanks @lex-li and @gunr2171!